# What is SA, SA1, SA2, SA3, SA4 stand for in 3GPP Spesifications

Tags: mobile, standardisation

In 3GPP spesification vocabulary document http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/21905.htm. I could not find definition for abbreviation definition for "SA", SA1 and soon that occur in 3GPP specification such as in Release document http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/29274.htm

What are these abbreviation stand for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SA is the 3GPP Technical Specification Group on ***Service and System Aspects***. There are subgroups on different topics:

- SA1: Services
- SA2: Architecture
- SA3: Security
- SA4: Codec
- SA5: Telecom Management
- SA6: Mission-critical Applications

You can find more info on the [3GPP website](http://www.3gpp.org/specifications-groups/sa-plenary).